# Dividir por secciones un archivo

Tags: python

quería saber como debería hacer lo siguiente :
Yo tengo el siguiente archivo:

```
Sección1

Texto ejemplo

Sección 2 

Texto de ejemplo
```

Quiero recorrer ese fichero(eso ya lo se hacer) y de ese fichero detectar donde empieza cada sección y guardar el contenido dentro de ella para luego realizar una serie de acciones.
Creo que se haría con un bucle recorriendo el contenido del fichero pero no se como debería hacer para detectar cada sección ya que sería un salto de línea:
Estoy muy perdido, lo agradecería.
EDITADO:
Esto es lo que tengo

```
import os

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import re
nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords= set(stopwords.words("spanish"))

import unidecode

import nltk
nltk.download('cess_esp')
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.corpus import cess_esp
from nltk import tag, tokenize


path = 'C:\\Users\\X\\X\\X\\X'
ficheros = os.listdir(path)

documentos = []

for nombrefichero in ficheros:
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, nombrefichero)): 
        fich = open(os.path.join(path, nombrefichero), "r",encoding='utf-8')
        text = fich.read()
        documentos.append(text)

        tokens=word_tokenize(text)
        limpio=[w.lower() for w in tokens if not w in stopwords]

        
        n_p= [item.replace('.',' ') for item in limpio]
        n_c= [item.replace('.','') for item in n_p]
        #n_a= unidecode.unidecode(n_c) DA ERROR 
        
                           
print(n_c)
```

SALIDA:
'Titulo\n\nTITULO PRUEBA. \n\nNoticia\n\n

Otro problema que me ha surgido ,es que intento quitar las tildes del documento pero no puedo con unidecode.

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que intentaste hasta ahora por favor (aunque no funcione)? De ese modo sabremos que no te estamos haciendo la tarea y así tendrás más posibilidades de recibir respuestas. Por favor lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para más información.

Comment: Ok, en un momento lo amplio.@DanteS.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es un pequeño parser. Suponiendo que cada título de sección empezara con la palabra "Seccion"/"Sección"/"seccion"..., podrías obtener el título y contenido de cada sección de forma estructurada iterando por cada una de las líneas del archivo y guardando el estado temporal del parser en variables:

```py
import unidecode

with open('secciones.txt') as f:
    lineas_archivo = f.readlines()

titulo_seccion_actual = ''
contenido_seccion_actual = ''
respuesta = []

for linea in lineas_archivo:
    if unidecode.unidecode(linea).lower().startswith("seccion"):
        if titulo_seccion_actual:
            respuesta.append({
                'titulo': titulo_seccion_actual.rstrip('\n'),
                'contenido': contenido_seccion_actual,
            })
            titulo_seccion_actual = ''
            contenido_seccion_actual = ''
        titulo_seccion_actual = unidecode.unidecode(linea)
    elif titulo_seccion_actual:
        contenido_seccion_actual += unidecode.unidecode(linea)

if titulo_seccion_actual:
    respuesta.append({
        'titulo': titulo_seccion_actual.rstrip('\n'),
        'contenido': contenido_seccion_actual,
    })
print(respuesta)
```

Para el contenido de archivo que has compartido, la salida sería:

```
[{'titulo': 'Seccion1', 'contenido': '\nTexto ejemplo\n\n'}, {'titulo': 'Seccion 2 ', 'contenido': '\nTexto de ejemplo\n'}]
```